# Logrotate is ignoring my configuration file

Tags: linux, logrotate

I'm facing an issue where logrotate is ignoring my configuration file:

```
/var/log/heartbeat/*log
{
rotate 1
size 1M
missingok
notifempty
nocompress
daily
create 440 https https
}
```

The files under that path get rotated ( 5 rotations ) after they reach 10k.
I replaced **size** by **minsize** and **maxsize** but the result remain the same.
Am I missing something ??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to rotate every day (daily) or only when it gets to 1M (size 1M)?  Currently you are saying both.

Comment: I used each option ( size and daily ) first, separately, then together but I always end up the same issue.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your global config file? Typically found at /etc/logrotate.conf

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the file inside `/etc/logrotate.d/` is owned and only writeable by root.  Out of security, Logrotate will (silently) refuse to execute files that are writable by others. If symlinked to another path, the entire path up to the file must be writable only by root.